# Setting ip helper-address to a broadcast address, bad idea?

Tags: networking, cisco, dhcp

**Info:**

- A number of vlans running on a 16 bit subnet
- All DHCP servers are on the same subnet (10.1.0.0/16)
- All switches and routers are Cisco

If I was to set the ip helper-address in our routers/switches to point to 10.1.255.255 would it be a bad idea?

What ramifications would it have on the network (speed, security, etc)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why wouldn't you just add an ip helper address for each DHCP server?

Comment: I have a strong feeling that ip helper is not design to convert unicast into broadcast, only the other way around. Like Joe - why would you do this?

Comment: Well, we are in the process of migrating our 6 DHCP servers to new DHCP servers and we have to go and update about 50 or so network devices and we would rather not have to do this again so by setting it as a broadcast address we only have to do it this once.

Comment: @pauska, I've tested it and it works but I'm thinking that it may cause a broadcast flood.

Comment: Broadcast floods are really a thing of the past with todays (enterprise) network gear.. Maybe you should try the Cisco support forum and see what they think? I have no idea if this is supported or not with IOS.

Comment: I don't see why there should be any concern about the additional broadcast traffic. For clients on the same subnet you already have link local broadcasts (255.255.255.255) related to DHCP. With your ip helper implementation you'll also have ip directed broadcasts (10.1.255.255) related to DHCP, but only when DHCP clients are requesting or renewing an ip address. I don't see that as being a big concern.

Comment: @joeqwerty, for the most part that's true, except it will broadcast more then just DHCP traffic, from my reading it will broadcast all UDP traffic related to the ports 37, 49, 53, 67, 68, 137, 138. My concern is that the traffic of 1000+ system all being broadcast to that subnet will overwhelm it.

Comment: You can use the "no ip forward-protocol" command to stop the forwarding of the other traffic.

Comment: @joeqwerty, I'm aware, thanks -- Doing testing to see what ramifications that will have on our network.

Comment: Seconding joeqwerty... if you turn up ip helpers on a segment you really (REALLY!) should disable default forwarding (no ip forward-protocol like he says) on ports you are not trying to forward.  This prevents troubleshooting really random problems on your network and saves some traffic to your 'ip helper x.x.x.x' machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a bad idea.

The Cisco documentation says this, "The helper address can be a specific DHCP server address, or it can be the network address if other DHCP servers are on the destination network segment. Using the network address enables other servers to respond to DHCP requests."

While this will save you work short term, the end result is that any rogue DHCP servers (accidental or malicious) in that /16 will be able to hand addresses to your entire network as well.  This doesn't seem like a good trade off to me.

If you are looking to save work, why not re-use the existing DHCP server IPs on the new servers?

Comment: Thanks, I new there had to be a bad reason to do this, but for some reason I didn't think of that one.

Comment: This is no more of a risk than already exists for DHCP clients on the same subnet. Implementing the ip-helper as described in the question doesn't increase the risk of having a rogue DHCP server, that risk exists regardless. It does though increase the impact of a rogue DHCP server.

Comment: @joeqwerty, agreed, but the scope of the problem is more limited without the rogue DHCP being reachable by the IP helper.

Comment: That's true. I just wanted to add my two cents.

Comment: DHCP Snooping can help you on the security front http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP_snooping

Comment: @JasonSeemann, also agree with that and highly recommend it if your environment supports it, but didn't add it to the discussion for two reasons.  First, it was a bit out of the scope of the question posed by the OP (best way to update ip-helper and reduce amount of work), and setting it up would be even more work.  Second, DHCCP snooping is available only from some vendors on certain platforms while the OP doesn't mention what brand/models of switches they are using.